# What is the meaning of "about" in "Love isn't all about flirting..." and "Love is about..."?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Love isn't all about flirting, hugs, kisses. Love is about having the ability to take all those things away and still having feelings for that person.
>
> (Source: [16quotes](http://16quotes.com/love-is-not-all-about-flirting-hugs-kisses/))

What is the meaning of **about** in this sentence?

What does **about** refer to?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase ***be what something is all about*** is defined on
[collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/be-what-something-is-all-about):

> to be the true purpose of or reason for something

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/be-about-something) defines ***be about something*** as:

> used for saying what the most basic or important aspect of a particular job, activity, or relationship is
>
> > Loving and sharing – that’s what marriage is about.
> >     **all about**: Good management is all about motivating your staff.

---

> Love isn't all about flirting, hugs, kisses.

This sentence says that flirting, etc. is not the true purpose of or reason for, or the most important aspect of love. It then goes on to say what the true purpose of it is:

> Love is about having the ability to...

= "The most important aspect of love is having the ability to..."

Answer (score 0):

Prepositions are difficult. The simplest meaning of *about* is near or close to: *I used to smoke about 30 cigarettes a day.* As with other prepositions, it has a number of other meanings as well, that are not always clearly related to one another.

In this case, it has the meaning of concerning, or having to do with a particular subject. The common use of *about* with this meaning is a story: *Goldilocks and the Three Bears* is a story *about* a girl named Goldilocks and three bears.

If you had to convey the meaning of your quote without using the word *about*, you could instead say this:

> Love isn't just a matter of flirting, hugs, kisses. Love means being able to take all those things away and still have feelings for that person.

Answer (score 0):

Most prepositions originally have spatial meanings, and the spatial meaning of *about* is "near."

So, 'A is about B' basically means that A is spatially near B. Wherever B goes, A always follows B and stays near B. This means that B is the most important or basic part or purpose of A. Hence the meaning.